# Why can't Jenkins see programs in /usr/bin?

Tags: jenkins

As a test, I added this to my Jenkinsfile:

```
steps {
    sh 'echo "SHOW TABLES;" | mysql'
}
```

but Jenkins said `mysql: command not found`. So I ran `which mysql` and it said `/usr/bin/mysql`. So I checked the `PATH` within Jenkins and it said `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`.

I assumed that if Jenkins' `PATH` contained `/usr/bin`, then Jenkins should be able to access the `mysql` executable by name.

However, when I run `ls -1 /usr/bin | wc -l` I can see that there are 1801 files. Within my Jenkinsfile, I have

```
steps {
   sh 'ls /usr/bin/ | wc -l'
}
```

and I get only 590 files.

Why is `/usr/bin` from Jenkins not the same as `/usr/bin` from outside of Jenkins? And how can I run `/usr/bin/mysql` from within Jenkins?

**EDIT:**
My Jenkinsfile specifies a docker agent like this:

```
agent {
    docker {
        image 'node:current'
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share more details about your setup? Mainly, is Jenkins deployed as a service or in a cotainer?

Comment: I set up Jenkins according to the getting started guide: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/getting-started/. It uses the declarative pipeline. The agent is docker, so it's in a container I guess? And I run Jenkins itself using `java -jar jenkins.war` as suggested in the getting started guide. I manage the Jenkins process with pm2 so that it's always running, i.e. `pm2 start "java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --httpPort=8090"`

Comment: Since the agent is running on docker, it has a different filesystem than your host, so `/usr/bin` if different outside the *container*, not Jenkins. You can read more about Docker and Jenkins [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).

Comment: Thank you for that pointer. It makes sense to me now why the /usr/bin programs can't be accessed. However, I still need to configure Docker to be able to access mysql... I will look into this.

Comment: You might use [mysql docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) instead of the node one. However, I recommend you to read a bit about Docker so you'll gather more knowledge about how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Inside the Jenkinsfile, I had to use

```
agent {
    dockerfile {
        args '--network="host"'
    }
}
```

and then I had to include a Dockerfile like this

```
FROM node:current

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install mysql-client -y
```

and that got mysql installed inside the Docker container. The `--network="host"` part allows mysql invocations from the Docker container to use `--host=127.0.0.1` to connect to the mysql server running on the host machine.